# Create XML representation of WCF binding instance

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I'm trying to write code to convert a WCF wsHttpBinding to customBinding, using the method described on [WSHttpBinding.CreateBindingElements Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpbinding.createbindingelements.aspx) 
.

```
Binding wsHttpBinding = ...
BindingElementCollection beCollection = originalBinding.CreateBindingElements();
foreach (var element in beCollection)
{
    customBinding.Elements.Add(element);
}
```

Once I have generated the custom binding, I want to generate an XML representation for that new custom binding. (The same XML representation that's found in an application's .config file).

Is there a way to do that?

(I'm aware of the tool referenced in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4217892/5688, but I need something I can call within an application and without depending on a service in the cloud)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class I was looking for was [System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceContractGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicecontractgenerator.aspx)

Exemple to generate a configuration for an instance of any kind of Binding:

```
public static string SerializeBindingToXmlString(Binding binding)
{
    var tempConfig = Path.GetTempFileName();
    var tempExe = tempConfig + ".exe";
    var tempExeConfig = tempConfig + ".exe.config";
    // [... create empty .exe and empty .exe.config...]

    var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(tempExe);
    var contractGenerator = new ServiceContractGenerator(configuration);
    string bindingSectionName;
    string configurationName;
    contractGenerator.GenerateBinding(binding, out bindingSectionName, out configurationName);

    BindingsSection bindingsSection = BindingsSection.GetSection(contractGenerator.Configuration);

    // this needs to be called in order for GetRawXml() to return the updated config
    // (otherwise it will return an empty string)
    contractGenerator.Configuration.Save(); 

    string xmlConfig = bindingsSection.SectionInformation.GetRawXml();

    // [... delete the temporary files ...]
    return xmlConfig;
}
```

This solution feels like a hack because of the need to generate empty temporary files, but it works.

Now I'll have to look for a way to have a fully in-memory instance of a System.Configuration.Configuration (maybe by writing my own implementation)

Answer (score 0):

Added missing code parts:

- // [... create empty .exe and empty .exe.config...]
- // [... delete the temporary files ...]

  ```
      public static string SerializeBindingToXmlString(Binding binding)
  {
      var tempConfig = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
      var tempExe = tempConfig + ".exe";
      var tempExeConfig = tempConfig + ".exe.config";
      using(System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(tempExe, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite))
      {

      }
      using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(tempExeConfig, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite))
      {
          fs.SetLength(0);
          using (System.IO.StreamWriter sr = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)) {
              sr.WriteLine("<?xml version= \"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>");
              sr.WriteLine(@"<configuration />");
          }
      }

      var configuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(tempExe);
      var contractGenerator = new System.ServiceModel.Description. ServiceContractGenerator(configuration);
      string bindingSectionName;
      string configurationName;
      contractGenerator.GenerateBinding(binding, out bindingSectionName, out configurationName);

     var bindingsSection =System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BindingsSection.GetSection(contractGenerator.Configuration);

      // this needs to be called in order for GetRawXml() to return the updated config
      // (otherwise it will return an empty string)
      contractGenerator.Configuration.Save();

      string xmlConfig = bindingsSection.SectionInformation.GetRawXml();
      System.IO.File.Delete(tempExeConfig);
      System.IO.File.Delete(tempExe);
      return xmlConfig;
  }
  ```